# How can I remove the spaces between lines in this bullet list in Divi?

Tags: wordpress, spacing, bulletedlist

In [this post](http://www.kuruzovich.com/guide-to-teaching-in-international-schools-in-bangkok/) on my site (under the Tier 1/Tier 2/Tier 3 section), I have run into an issue with the spacing between individual bullet points. When I first published it a few years ago, the spacing between each bullet was the same as other lines on the site. However, after one of the updates to either Wordpress or Divi, the spaces ballooned.

I've tried several of the solutions on this site, including adding a style element to the *ul* portion, but this simply adjusts the spacing between the lines in each bullet rather than between the bullet points themselves.

Does anyone know how to reduce this space in order to align it with everything else on the site?

Here is the code from one of the three columns:

```
<ul>
<li><strong>Status</strong>: Most often not-for-profit</li>
<li><strong>Ownership</strong>: Typically owned by&nbsp;parents and operated as a foundation school</li>
<li><strong>Accreditation</strong>:&nbsp;National (ONESQA) and multiple international (CIS/NEASC/WASC/CfBT)</li>
<li><strong>Fees</strong>: High, ranging between THB 400,000 to 925,000 depending on the level
<ul>
<li>Additional fees are usually required for enrollment as well</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><strong>Staffing</strong>: Typically employ Western teaching staff, but are willing to hire licensed teachers of any nationality</li>
<li><strong>Student Body</strong>: Set cap for Thais (20 – 30%)</li>
</ul>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<strong>Salary &amp; Benefits</strong>
<ul>
<li>Monthly Salary (Gross): THB 135,000 - 275,000</li>
<li>THB 28,000 - 60,000 housing allowance or provided housing</li>
<li>Annual airfare (following initial 2-year contract)</li>
<li>Generous responsibility allowances</li>
<li>Annual bonus equivalent to one or one and a half month's salary</li>
<li>Full health and dental insurance</li>
<li>Pension fund</li>
<li>Relocation/settling-in allowance</li>
<li>Personal professional development fund</li>
</ul>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<strong>Typical Hire</strong>
<ul>
<li>4-10+ years of experience in international setting</li>
<li>Bachelor's, master's or&nbsp;graduate diploma in education</li>
<li>Frequently has teaching license in home country</li>
<li>Exemplary performance in past positions</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask] and [mcve]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, not just on an external site. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: without posting any code, we cant help

Comment: That being said, it looks like you are talking about the 16px top margin those LI elements get from a rule containing the selector `.et_pb_text li` – rather trivial to figure out using browser dev tools.

Comment: Sorry - I've just updated the question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
.et_pb_text li {
  margin-top: 5px; 
}
.et_pb_text li ul {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Add this CSS to `Dashbord > Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS` and change the **5px**  value to your preferred one.

Comment: I just did, but as a new member, it unfortunately doesn't appear.